# Isometric Game World Boundaries Equation

Tags: libgdx, isometric, tiles

I ran into a problem last night and I can't solve it since.
I'm making an isometric game based on tiles with equal rows and columns.
Now I made moving entities which should turn whenever they reach the boundaries of the world. As I illustrated on the picture they are turning back on the upper boundaries (green) , but not on the lower ones (red).
I tried various equations on the lower part, but i cannot figure out for the life of me what is the lower parts code. What would be an appropriate solution for the shrinking lines?

`boolean checkBounds(){
        float absX = Math.abs(getX());
        float absY = Math.abs(getY());
        if(absY*2-absX<0 || ??? ) return false
        else return  true;
    }`

[image]

Comment: Usually an isometric game will use the diamond layout exclusively for display. All world & gameplay logic is done in a separate coordinate system, with the axes aligned to the rows & columns (so eg. (2, 0) is the third column of the first row, assuming 0-based indices), and transformed to the isometric perspective only for the drawing step. This kind of switch will likely make a lot of your logic much simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate on what DMGregory said... you don't want to imagine them moving on diamond tiles, but rather imagine them moving on the ordinary grid you've set up as a 2D array in memory. *That* is what you do your movement and collision detection / resolution on; at least at this early stage.

This way your transition between (unoccupied) tiles becomes a simple fractional value, for example, `xFractionToNextCell == 0.4` means you're 40% of the way on your movement to the next tile, in `x`. You can do the same for `y`. Once it hits `1.0` AND you are at the edge of the map, you can turn.

Using the view-transformed grid just unnecessarily complicates things in this regard. So rather work in the original 2D array co-ordinates.

Comment: Yes I was thinking about how should i seperate the drawing and the logic of the game based on DMGregory's answer. I got stuck with the drawing coordinates, when I should just translate the simple positions. This method will definietly work for the bounds thanks.